# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS another Ubuntu 14.04 host machine with LXD hypervisor

Tags: 14.04, lxde, hyper-v

How to install Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS on another Ubuntu 14.04 host machine. I have downloaded LXD by `sudo apt-get install xld`

i have Ubuntu 14.04 .iso image with me on my pendrive.

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lxd-images import ubuntu --alias ubuntu
lxc launch ubuntu your-container
lxc exec your-container bash
```

That will import an Ubuntu 14.04 image into LXD and spawn a container from it, then give you a shell inside it.